# Backbone parsing this.model.destroy

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest, backbone.js

**INTRO**

I Am having having issues trying to parse my models before I send them to my web service.

I have a REST web services set-up which is working fine, I have my backbone set-up to parse the web services JSON reponse, which also works fine. I am able to display the JSON objects

The problem is when I try to delete or update the model, backbone never parses the model before it sends it back to the server and the server always receives null.
Here is my code:

**Teacher Model**

```
window.Teacher = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "http://localhost:8080/SIMS/resource/teacher",
    defaults: {
          "id": null,
        "Name":  "",
        "Password":  "",
        "email":  "",
        "dob":  "",
        "type":  ""

      },

          parse: function(response){

              console.log("................................. response test.........");
              response.id = response.idTeacher;
              console.log("..........."+response.name);
              console.log("..........."+response.idTeacher);
              response.Password = response.password;
              response.Name = response.name;
              delete response.name;
              delete response.password;
              delete response.idTeacher;
              return response;


          } ,

          toJSON: function(){
              var attrs = _.clone(this.attributes);
              attrs.name = attrs.Name;
              delete attrs.Name;
              attrs.password = attrs.Password;
              delete attrs.Password;
              attrs.idTeacher = attrs.id;
              delete attrs.id;
              return attrs;
          }
});

window.TeacherCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Teacher,
    url: "http://localhost:8080/SIMS/resource/teacher",

        parse: function(response){


             for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++)
              {
                console.log("...........help");
                response[i].id = response[i].idTeacher;
                response[i].Password = response[i].password;
                response[i].Name = response[i].name;
                console.log(".........."+response[i].Name);
                delete response[i].name;
                delete response[i].password;
                delete response[i].idTeacher;

              }
           return response ;



        }

});
```

**Teacher View: save function**

```
saveTeacher: function() {
        this.model.set({
            Name: $('#Name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            Password: $('#Password').val(),
            dob: $('#dob').val(),
            type: $('#type').val()

        });
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            var self = this;
            app.teacherList.create(this.model, {
                success: function() {
                    app.navigate('admin/teacher/'+self.model.id, false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.model.save();
        }

        return false;
    },
```

**Web Service**

```
@PUT @Path("{id}")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void update(Teacher T){

   System.out.println("Updating Teacher:" + T.getName());
   teacherejb.edit(T);

}
```

**Question**

Since I have the parse function I now use `.attributes` instead of `toJSON()` and this works fine.

Example:

```
   render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    },
```

But when trying to call `this.model.save` in the `saveteahcer` function it never parses before I send it to the server, Im not sure how to parse it first and then send it to the server. When I debug the code the web service always receives null, how do I get my web service to properly receive the teacher object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parse method is called **after the server response**, see [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse):

> ### parsemodel.parse(response, options)
>
> parse is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in fetch, and save.

I would suggest that you use [**validate**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) to modify/update the data before send it to server:

> ### validatemodel.validate(attributes, options)
>
> This method is left undefined, and you're encouraged to override it with your custom validation logic, if you have any that can be performed in JavaScript. **By default validate is called before save** [...]